# How to compare varchar parameter to null in a natively compiled stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am migrating some tables and stored procedures to in-memory optimized tables and natively compiled stored procedures and am getting stuck on a null comparison.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyInMemTable]
(
    [MyId] int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    [MyData] varchar(900) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2 not null
    CONSTRAINT [PK_MyInMemTable] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([MyId])
) WITH (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON, DURABILITY=SCHEMA_ONLY)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_InsertIntoMyInMemTable](@MyData varchar(900))
    WITH NATIVE_COMPILATION, SCHEMABINDING, EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS 
BEGIN ATOMIC WITH (TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL = SNAPSHOT, LANGUAGE = N'English')
    IF @MyData IS NOT NULL  
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.[MyInMemTable] (MyData) VALUES (@MyData)
        SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END
    ELSE
        SELECT 0
END
```

I get the following error:

```
Msg 12327, Level 16, State 101, Procedure sp_InsertIntoMyInMemTable, Line 306
Comparison, sorting, and manipulation of character strings that do not use a *_BIN2 collation is not supported with natively compiled stored procedures.
```

How do I specify a collation on the parameter, or is there an alternative way to get this null comparison to work?

Comment: Does something like this work? INSERT INTO dbo.[MyInMemTable] (MyData) VALUES (@MyData Collate Database_Default) -- Replace Database_Default with desired collation

Comment: The problem isn't the insert--it is the comparison to null.  So even if I change the body of the stored proc to "IF @MyData IS NOT NULL SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0" I get the same issue.

Comment: You can add " Collate {Collation Value} " pretty much anywhere you can specify a field with collation it seems. Did you try " IF @MyData Collate {Collation} IS NOT NULL"?

Comment: Thanks!  That did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please see the comments from @Eric J, above.

You can add " Collate {Collation Value} " pretty much anywhere you can specify a field with collation it seems. Did you try " IF @MyData Collate {Collation} IS NOT NULL"?

I just put this as answer to help people finding it.